# How can I make an comparison of 3 conditions without a switch or if in C#?

Tags: c#

I have to compare a value, if the value is less or equal than 3, then do something, if value is bettwen 4 and 27, then do something else, but if the value is more than 28 do something else, is there any elegant way which doesn't consume a lot of resources and I can avoid using switch of if?? I have to compare around 60k+ values.

Comment: if and switch does not consume much resources. other solutions will likely consume more. Multithread your application

Comment: 60k values isn't very many, not for a modern computer. Have you tried a simple implementation to see whether it meets your performance requirements? I bet your computer can do 60k (or even 120k) comparisons in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @gladoscc so, if I'm doing a migration I've better use switch or if?

Comment: What resources do you wish to not consume much of?

Comment: @GregHewgill I didn't make the code, but i don't want to make an if statement neither a switch, that's what i'm asking for

Comment: @MartinJames ram, processor, bandwidth, I'm doing a migration and I run the script from my computer and upload data in a server...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're averse to using a switch or if? They're basic conditionals .. they'll even be converted to roughly the same IL..

Comment: OK. 60K+ function-pointer table will not use much CPU.

Comment: if(v<=3){}else if(4<27){}else{}

That will not use much CPU, memory.. etc.

Comment: anything more complex like messing with bits will be slower, really

Comment: Did you see that there is an *actual* performance bottleneck revolving around the comparisons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything faster. You may be able to speed things up a little if you know how your data is distributed. For example, if most values are above 27 then check for that condition first, etc. If your data was sorted, you could also find a way to take advantage of that.

Comment: but some code that I could use in order to make the comparison in fewer lines of code?

Comment: if(v<=3){}else if(v<27){}else{}

Comment: if you want to write something more compact, just use the conditional operator x < 3 ? doSomething() : (x < 28 ? doSomethingElse : doYetSomethingElse)

Comment: OK, how about a sorted const table of structs with the start/end index of the range and a function pointer or class instance?   You could binary-search the table and call the function/method as appropriate for the range.

Answer (score 1):

Use quicksort to sort the values. This implementation will reduce the amount of if comparisons, but is probably not faster.

Answer (score 1):

I timed a check like this:

```
if (i <= 3) {
  DoSomething();
} else if (i <= 27) {
  DoSomethingElse();
} else {
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Doing this 60000 times takes about 35 microseconds on my computer. If that is too long for whatever you are doing, you have to rethink what you are doing instead of trying a different way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do this code, the thing is I'm doing this from my computer sendig data through SQL statement to a server in a VPN, also this is not the only thing the script will do, I just wanted to make it a little faster if there was smoe option aviable!

Comment: @poz2k4444: In that case it wouldn't make any difference even if you could do the comparisons in zero time. A single round trip to the server takes at least 100 times longer than all the 60000 comparisons.

Comment: That's what I was talking about, I think more code better performance?

Comment: @poz2k4444: You could set up an array of delegates for all possible values and probably shave off a few microseconds, but you said that you don't want to consume a lot of resources. Also, that would only be a gain if you were doing this an awful lot of times so that you could reuse the huge array and make up for the time creating the array in the first place.

Comment: Sadly the data will be used just one time and then I'll use something else, but thanks for the advice, I'll sort it and then search for what I know has more matches, thanks anyway!

Comment: @poz2k4444: Sorting the array takes about 50 times longer than just doing the comparisons, so you can't use that to make it faster.

Comment: The thing is I have to sort it by three differents standards, so I think it's worth the shot, besides, the sort will be done in my computer, and then I'll upload the data, see the answer that I accept ;)

Comment: @poz2k4444: If your data was already sorted, you could take advantage of that, just as that answer says, but if the data isn't sorted already, there is no gain in sorting it. Actually it will only make the code slower.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator (`?:`) and do something like this:

```
i = (i <= 3) ? DoSomething() : (i <= 27) ? DoSomething(): DoSomething();
```

That is just more condensed, and takes 571400 nanoseconds on my computer (6gb ram), and `if..else` statements take 407400 nanoseconds, so the `if..else` statements are faster, but the conditional operator is more condensed.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is I'm doing this from my computer sendig data through SQL statement to a server in a VPN, also this is not the only thing the script will do, I just wanted to make it a little faster if there was some option aviable!

Comment: I just wanted to show you all of the options :), but the if...else statements are faster, especially when you are working with large amounts of data, as long as it doesn't get out of control like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11718/continues-if-statements